# set text NullPointerException inside try

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, textview

I meet strange problemm with setText.
I have json object which is parced from internet
This json is not null and `json.getString("not_status") == 1`, 
I am getting `NullPointerExeption` when program tries to execute `active.setText(json.getString("not_status"));` // it is on line 92
if i change `active.setText(json.getString("not_status"));` to `active.setText("abc");` and move it outside `try{}` block it works fine. Question is - can i setSext inside `try{}`?

```
JSONObject json = null;
TextView active = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_atc_active);
// some code to put data to json
try {
if (json!=null) {
Log.d("Gues: ", "5_1 " +json.getString("not_status"));
active.setText(json.getString("not_status"));
}
}
catch (JSONExaption e){
e.printTrace
}
```

Log.d("Gues: ", "5_1 " +json.getString("not_status")); gives me followwing, that prove json.getString("not_status") == 1

```
04-16 08:50:06.575: D/Gues:(1189): 5_1 1
```

Log

```
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.regtest/com.example.regtest.AddToCheckActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at com.example.regtest.AddToCheckActivity.onCreate(AddToCheckActivity.java:92)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-16 08:33:12.944: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     ... 11 more
```

json output

```
04-16 08:50:06.554: D/JSON(1189): {"not_id":"7217801","not_section":"1973","not_street":"m","not_sqTotal":"0","not_sqLiving":"0","not_sqKitchen":"0","not_sqLand":"0","not_unitLand":"0","not_sqHouse":"0","not_flat":"3","not_floor":"0","not_floors":"0","not_title":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0430 3 \u043a\u043e\u043c\u043d\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u044b \u0432 \u043d\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0439\u043a\u0430\u0445 \u0411\u0435\u043b\u0430\u044f \u0426\u0435\u0440\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044c \u0413\u043b\u0443\u0448\u043a\u0438","not_text":"","user_phone1":"+38111111111","user_phone2":"","user_contact":" ","not_region":"1","not_district":"2","not_settle":"34","not_price":"99999999","not_photo":"a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:\"id\";s:7:\"8036442\";s:4:\"desc\";s:0:\"\";}}","not_date":"2013-04-15 10:46:26","not_date_till":"2013-05-15 00:00:00","not_up":"0","not_premium":"0","not_status":"1","not_huurl":"http:\/\/mirkvartir.ua\/offers\/view\/7217801-prodazha-3-komnatnoj-kvartiry-v-novostrojkax-belaya-cerkov-glushki.html","region_title":"\u041a\u0438\u0435\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f","district_title":"\u0411\u0435\u043b\u0430\u044f \u0426\u0435\u0440\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044c","settle_title":"\u0413\u043b\u0443\u0448\u043a\u0438","section_title":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0430 \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440 \u0432 \u043d\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0439\u043a\u0430\u0445"}
```

json code

```
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient

            String u = url;
            u = u +"?";
            //System.setProperty("192.168.4.200", "3128");

//          if (httpClient == null) {
//              httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//              Log.d("New Client","bad");
//          }
            httpClient = HttpClientFactory.getThreadSafeClient();
            //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = c.getClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            for(int i =0;i<params.size();i++)
            {
            u =u +params.get(i).getName()+"="+params.get(i).getValue() +"&";
            }
            Log.d("your url is",u);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            Log.d("data is sent", "true");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        Log.d("wait", "true");
        try {


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

Comment: stacktrace please....

Comment: TextView active = ...; that would be the interesting part. If your Log.d doesnt get a npe, active has to be null.

Comment: Did u link the text view correctly.

Comment: If your observations are correct, then it's relatively safe to conclude that `active` is `null`.

Comment: what is on line number 92 in AddToCheckActivity.java file ?

Comment: line 92 is active.setText(json.getString("not_status"));

Comment: Please declare TextView active at class level variable and initialize it in onCreate() method.

Comment: Please post your full code ... i want to see json code...

Comment: if you write active.setText("abc"), does it still freeze? If yes, there is a problem with textview initialization, if it does not, there is a problem with your json.

Comment: Chirag, declaration as a class variable did not helped
Analizer, a change line 92 to ative.SetText("abc") still have error.

Comment: when i removing active.setText("abc") from try block and put it outside it works fine.

Comment: Try debugging the code. In line 92, is active null, or is json null, or is json.getString("not_status") null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mount the view to java using findViewById(R.id.TextViewname);  and then do the set text.Since you catch will only catch JSONException cause you mentioned only that.Try mounting the views its should work fine.

Comment: i wrote TextView active = ... just for shorteness, changed to actual declaration

Comment: Try ssetting text like this and plz let me know how it works.... active.setText(json.getString("not_status")+"");

Comment: it was already proposed by some one and then removed. Just because it does not make any effort i tried again and that still does not work

Comment: Try making the textview declared global...i predict inside trycatch its not getting acess to the textview....an c how it works???

Comment: 1.Declaration global, 2.mount inside oncreate using findviewbyId, 3.set the text inside try catch.....try this hope it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to initialize active textview before use it.

```
active = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewname); 
active.setText(json.getString("not_status"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
TextView active = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_atc_active);
```

Only works if the view is currently on the screen (that is, you called `setContentView` on an xml that contains that ID, or you've added it manually.

So it could well be your `active` is NULL, and then any call using that will throw a `nullpointerException`

Comment: when i remove setText part, i dont have exeption

Comment: That's logical if `active` is null, isn't it? You are doing `null.whatever` which is the archetype of making a `nullPointerException`

Comment: THe point is: did you do a `setContentView`, and is that id in that xml, did you not?

Comment: setContentView is setUped properly, tv_atc_active is id of textview declared in xml
active.setText("abc") works outside try{}